# Detect EndOfStream in a stream field on a WCF service using streaming messages (Mtom)

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming

My web method receives a simple structure, where one of the fields is a stream.
It is something like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class MyFile:IDisposable
{
    Stream _stream;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream stream
    {
        get { return _stream; }
        set { _stream= value; }
    }

    String _Name;
    [MessageHeader]
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
}
#region IDisposable Support
private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            _File.Dispose();
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
        // TODO: set large fields to null.

        disposedValue = true;
    }
}
public void submitFile(MyFile file)
{
  using (var fs = File.Create(@"d:\temp\" + file + ".pdf"))
    {
        int len;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        do
        {
            len = file.stream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        } while (len != 0);
    }
}
```

This code causes an error on the client side. The client aborts saying the stream was closed by the server, when the client is still sending data though the stream.

Problem is **how do i detect the end of stream?**

I know that the comunication can be suspended, or the server can process faster then the cliente, so no data to read doesn't mean the client has send all the data.
Http post should have some tag on the end that tells the server the request ended, so should be some simple way in WCF to get that information.

Sending an mark on the end of file is what i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the simplest possible solution?

```
          file.stream.CopyTo(fs);
```

Comment: Yes, and it works. But with that aproach the server has to keep all data in memory.

Comment: No it doesn't. The file-stream will flush to disk when the internal buffer fills up. There's also an overload of CopyTo where you can specify the buffer size.

Comment: You are Rigth. According to the documentation It does.
Still can't pass an 6GB file across the wire because client is trying to allocate all file in memory, but that is another problem. Thanks.